# In C# Writing to Excel, How to show a big number as it is (Not with scientific notation)?

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, closedxml

I am sending an excel file from backend. I have got long numbers for some cards' numbers. I need to show them in Excel but I want all of them to be number and edit them as it is (sometimes the value and the shown text differs, I want them to be the same).
The proplem is when I set the data type of the cell like

```
    var currentRow = 1;
    var cardNo = "9993232323232320";
    worksheet.Column(6).CellsUsed().SetDataType(XLDataType.Text);
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).Value = cardNo;
    worksheet.Column(6).CellsUsed().SetDataType(XLDataType.Text);//Doesn't matter if it is before or after
```

I can set the value with SetValue method, which makes the cell string:

```
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).SetValue(cardNo);
```

But in this case, excel adds an apostrophe in front of the number, which makes it a text seemingly. When you try to edit the cell, the apostrophe exists in front of the number.

Lastly I tried to set the NumberFormatId of the cell by

```
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).Value = cardNo;
    worksheet.Column(6).Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 1;
```

For information about NumberFormatId: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML-wiki/blob/master/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table.md
In this case the cell is a number, seemingly a number, but again when you try to edit the row, the row contains a scientific number.

I can achieve what I want over excel like this:

- Go to a column, right click, Format Cells
- Numbers tab -> Number
- Options-> Decimal Places, set to 0, Format Code set to 0.
  And then add a number to a row in that column.

Or like this:

- Go to a column -> right click -> format cells
- Numbers Tab -> Text -> OK.
  And edit the lines.

How can I achieve the same thing in ClosedXML in C#

Comment: `cardNo` is a string, not a number. Numeric styles won't affect it. `excel adds an apostrophe in front of the number, which makes it a text seemingly` because it *is* a string. Parse it into a `long` or `decimal` if you want it to be treated as a string. ClosedXML or any other library can't guess that you really want this to be converted into a number

Comment: Short answer: use `var cardNo = 9993232323232320;` or `var cardNo=long.Parse("9993232323232320");`

Comment: `When you try to edit the cell, the apostrophe exists in front of the number.` that's how Excel works. That's not a problem.

Comment: I think there may be a bug, it works if you set it by individual cell e.g. `ws.Cell("F2").Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 1;` , but not by the entire column.

Comment: Giving the long number version of the long string does not effect the results and I don't want to see an apostrophe, the people that will use this excel may not want this @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Kevin You must add .CellsUsed() after Column like  ```worksheet.Column(6).CellsUsed().Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 1;```. I found this afterwards. But when you try to edit the row, the cell appears to be a scientific number. I want the row be the same all the time, even when you try to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the wiki for number formats: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML-wiki/blob/master/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table.md

In the question what was trying to be achieved was this:

> - Go to a column -> right click -> format cells
> - Numbers Tab -> Text -> OK. And edit the lines.

By looking at the NumberFormatId table in the given link, the Id of this operation is 49 so the code must be `worksheet.Column(6).CellsUsed().Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 49;`

And another problem is you have to use SetValue instead of setting Value like:
`worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).SetValue(cardNo);`

After that it must work.